# Querying for GroupBy in Django

Tags: python, django, group-by, django-queryset, django-orm

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
    

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='book_author')
    price = models.SmallIntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Hello there!
I've been trying to group by the cost of books in the above model according to the author (as there can be multiple authors for a single book). I know it can be done using groupby but I don't know how to query for it in Django ORM, I tried searching the web but didn't get the relevant solution.

What I'm trying to do is,
for e.g., if a book 'Wonder' has two authors 'A' and 'B' and they have written together with other books as well,
like 'Wonder' by 'A' and 'B' and
'New' by 'A' and 'B'

So, I want to query for the books with the combination of their authors + a total cost field of all the books written by the authors (many-to-many author combination).

If there is a way, please help, and sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: I doubt there is better introduction to grouping in django than this article https://hakibenita.com/django-group-by-sql

Comment: can you add a proper example to demonstrate, what exists and what answer do you expect because the example you have provided is hard to visualize and understand your issue?

Comment: Sure, what I want is,
suppose...a book named 'Wonder' written by 'A' and 'B' and another book named 'New' written by the same 'A' and 'B', So when we get all the books I want an attribute in each queryset named 'totalCost' (it can be anything) which gives me the total summation of the price of books written by the same author combo.

Comment: so do you provide the author combo `A` and `B` as input or book `Wonder` as your input?

Comment: No, I didn't provide the combo, I've linked authors A and B using ManyToMany relation.

Answer (score 0):

This includes little coding and workaround.

Consider the `main_book` instance you want to work on ( lets assume its book `Wonder` ).
Later,
get all the authors of the book, like below

`authors = set(main_book.author.all())`

Later filter out all the books which have these set of `authors` in them like this,

`books = Book.objects.filter(author__in=authors)`

Then here comes the exact logic,

```
total_cost = 0
for book in books:
    if authors == set(book.author.all()):
        total_cost += book.price
print(total_cost)
```

This should return you the cost of all book that has same `authors` has `main_book`.
Remember, as you said in comments and questions, only those books are considered which have the same set of authors in them, no more, no less.

Comment: Can we do it using a single query or using annotate so that I don't have to reformat my data to add total_cost in each queryset ?

Comment: I couldn't find any.